# SQL Server stored procedure - logic to return 3 character line numbers that includes alphanumeric results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

```
OPEN abcTables
    FETCH NEXT FROM abcTables INTO @TableName
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 

    BEGIN
        SET @SQLTableName = (SELECT CHAR(39) + @TableName + CHAR(39))
        SET @LineNum      = CHAR(39) + dbo.[GetabcLine](@TableName) + CHAR(39)
        /*                = (SELECT CHAR (39)+ CASE WHEN REPLACE(RIGHT(@TableName, 2), 'e', '0') = '00'
                                                    THEN '0' 
                                                    ELSE REPLACE(RIGHT(@TableName, 2), 'e', '0')
                                               END
                                                 + CHAR(39))
        */ Requires more sophisticated logic to return 3 char line numbers that includes alphanumeric results
        SET @SQLCmd       = 'UPDATE ' + @TableName + ' ' + '    
                                SET [Job#] = jobs.[mode#]
                                  , [Line] = ' + @LineNum + '
                                  , [StartofJob] = jobs.[start date] 
                                  , [EndofJob] = CASE WHEN jobs.[end date] = GETDATE() THEN NULL ELSE jobs.[end date] END
                                  , [ModelID] = CASE WHEN [ModelID] IS NULL THEN ' + @dent + ' 
                                                     WHEN [ModelID] = ' + @Tnie + ' THEN ' + @ari + ' 
                                                     ELSE [ModelID]
                                                END
                             FROM ' + @TableName + ' hrb ' + '
                             INNER JOIN #Jobs jobs ON hrb.Time1 BETWEEN jobs.[start date] AND jobs.[end date] ' + '
                             WHERE jobs.[line] = ' + @LineNum + ' ' + '
                             AND [Time1] >= DATEADD(DAY,-90, GETDATE())'

EXEC (@SQLCmd)

FETCH NEXT FROM abcTables INTO @TableName

END 

CLOSE abcTables
DEALLOCATE abcTables

DROP TABLE #Jobs
```

END

Stored procedure to return production machine values from one database to another from one sql server to another. For now its picking up the data thats only two characters but a new production line has been added and an addition to recognize the 3 char line number which includes alphanumeric. any suggestions?

Comment: You're missing some stuff.

Comment: its not allowing me to post the whole stuff here

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to modify your function to the new change of 3 characters suffix and matching your jobs table.

```
dbo.[GetabcLine](@TableName) --==>
SET @LineNum = CASE WHEN REPLACE(RIGHT(@TableName, 3), 'e', '0') = '00'
                                                    THEN '0' 
                                                    ELSE REPLACE(RIGHT(@TableName, 3), 'e', '0')
                                               END
```

I includes your script in my online SQL playground here:
https://sqleditor.net/q/BJpRYsHuM

You can save your version and show me more details about your question.